# Kitchen sink backing up with no apparent blockage

Tags: plumbing, drain, kitchen-sink, blockage

We're having trouble stopping our kitchen sink drain from backing up. The sink now backs up nearly instantly (after a few seconds), previously it took a bit longer to backup.

We've tried on multiple times with different methods to fix it ourselves including with a plunger, alkaline drain un-blocker as well as caustic soda.

At one point, the bathroom sink (close to kitchen) also backed up. From that we deduced where a blockage might be and unscrewed the pipe and cleared out a lot of white sediment that had built up along the bottom side of the pipe. This "solved" the problem for around a day, but then the problem returned.

After this, we researched another method that involved pushing a 3m spring/screw down the pipe in order to try and pull up a blockage. We did this from the sink end and from the other end of a near 6m inaccessible stretch of pipe that ends near a junction of piping (see diagram below). Nothing was recovered from this, it seems as if there may be no physical blockage.

We've all but run out of ideas at this point, but some research on the internet suggests that the problem might be related to air/suction, it seems to fit with (1) the blockage occuring nearly instantly, (2) not finding a physical blockage & (3) we've unscrewed the pipes at the sink and a junction enough times that we could easily have introduced a problem without realising it, not being plumbers. I've also confirmed that there is no water backed up near where the pipes all join up before going underground.

We have a dishwasher that also feeds into the drain straight after the kitchen sink. This has some sort of non-return valve which we've also unscrewed a couple of times and at one point it leaked causing us to screw it up very tightly, which could have introduced a problem for all we know. We're not sure how it works, or whether we should have screwed it up tightly, but the problem appears to remain even when unscrewed and holding a hand over the opening.

I've included some photos and a diagram, on the off chance that it helps, it's a problem that's been with us for a while. The diagram shows one of the difficulties with diagnosing the problem, in that a near 6m stretch of pipe after the sink is not accessible.

If no physical blockage is present, what would be causing the sink to backup? Is there some kind of air-trap or pressure problem that could be the cause?

Any general advice for how to investigate/fix is welcome, particularly as the covid situation makes this a bad/impossible time to get a professional to investigate.

**Update**
I doubt it matters, but just in case, we're in the UK. Also, there are no visible drain vents anywhere along the system we're discussing. There is however a central heating system feeding into the same drain and the seal is not air tight, with two 1.5cm pipes feeding into the drain.

Also, all of this plumbing is on the groundfloor.

**Diagram**

[image: diagram of system]

**Photos**

**Under kitchen sink**

[image: Pipes under sink showing dishwasher junction]

**Drainage junctions**

[image: Drainage junctions]

**Specifics of what solved it**

Obviously all of the advice on here was sound, but I wanted to highlight some of the specifics that helped solve this, in case it helps someone else.

The problem turned out to be a simple blockage, a build up of sludge, but our diagnostics turned out to be flawed. In the end on advice from this question, we bought a 6m snake - https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000O55KJC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

The above worked well, and far better than our 3m snake without the blue attachment.

The specific technique that helped was to time how long it took to back up. From the volume of the pipe and from how much water your tap flows per second you can then work out where the blockage must start. From that we could tell the problem wasn't the piping around the sink, it was the inaccessible part.

We then proceeded to snake it, two techniques helped, turning the coil when a blockage was struck, but also sliding it backwards and forwards. We undid the bathroom sink junction at the opposite end to see if the snake was through and when we came out the other side. We then put the garden hose pipe down the sink and turned it on, it still backed up, so we continued snaking and looking for the blockage. Eventually a lot of sludge came out and we had an idea we had made progress. It's not been long, but the sink now drains. And if it backs up again we have a fair idea that the same procedure will help.

Thanks again for all that helped us fix this!

take off all the kitchen piping

Comment: How far did you snake the line from the kitchen end?  Did it reach the end of the inaccessible stretch of pipe?  On the second picture, where does the inaccessible stretch of pipe connect in?

Comment: Is it possible that's just trapped air, and there's a vent problem?

Comment: On another note, the corrugated sections is not approved for use in drain pipes,  the walls must be smooth. In the second photo, is this a 'DIY' set up and proper vent lines were installed?

Comment: Those slopes don't seem steep enough to drain solids properly. Somewhere else is your soil stack, and without an air inlet to let air in you will have problems draining. Perhaps that backed up and sealed. Finding it will be hard though.

Comment: @Programmer66 we can't be sure, but we think we covered the full length of the inaccessible pipe by going in from both ends. The inaccessible pipe connects just behind the vertical section in the picture.

Comment: @Duston we have read the odd thing about air flow, but don't understand how we can check or what we should have.

Comment: @Programmer66 if it was originally DIY, it wouldn't surprise us, given the state of repair of the rest of the house, but we don't know for sure. How can we check for vent lines?

Comment: Look at the roof directly above that area of the house, you should see an open-ended pipe sticking through the roof. That would be a sewer/drain vent.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that the inaccessible pipe was snaked,  I thought 'inaccessible' meant that you could not snake it.  Based on this new information, this is most likely a air vent issue creating the blockage.

Comment: Per your comment, "we can't be sure, but we think we covered the full length of the inaccessible pipe by going in from both ends. The inaccessible pipe connects just behind the vertical section in the picture."  You would need to snake the inaccessible pipe complete (yes 6m and more) from one end, not partially from each end.  Once you are sure the snake is traversing all the way through,  Start rotating the snake as much as possible.  You are trying to distrube the water blockage enough to break the vacuum seal.  If this works, a lot of water (6m) may come gushing out. be prepared.

Comment: To be clear - a lot of water (waste-sewage).

Comment: Just found this on the internet, "BAAM" high pressure drain cleaner.  This would be a lot easier.  But I would connect directly through the drain in the wall in the kitchen if possible.  You might generate enough pressure to offset the water seal.  This is not a recommendation for the product, never had to use one.  Do your own review of how good it works.  The best solution if possible is to locate the vent pipe.  Common cause of vent blockage are, bird nest, leaves, its no longer capped, drain blockage at the joint causing water to enter the drain pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment by @Duston,  If the vent pipe is completely blocked, a vacuum can form which is holding the water in the drain pipe.  The snake is only traversing through the water.

Another reasons based on new information, is that not enough vent pipe were installed or installed at proper locations in the drainage system.

***Add additional information on drain vents***
Below are pictures of drain vents, roof and wall.  The wall shows two new vents, the small is the air vent for the sink, the larger is the vent for the range hood.
Hope this helps.
[image: Roof drain vent]

[image: Wall Drain View w Range hood vent]

Comment: Thanks Programmer66 - what would the vent pipe look like?

Comment: The air vent pipe looks like a drain pipe and normally from the drain goes straight up to the Roof.  The vent pipes are those strange pipes in the roof that people wondered what the pipes are for.  LOL.  Sometimes the vent pipes may exit out of the side of the house, but there are codes that limit where it may exit, example a certain distance from any window, etc.

Comment: I can't see proper vents in the way described, but couldn't the bathroom sink / bath act as a vent? Also, the central heating system waste flow runs into the same drainage (I've only just spotted it) and it's not sealed properly. The ventilation sounds like the right cause, but I'm wondering whether the problem developed at the dishwasher join. It was quite loose before it leaked. I screwed up tightly thinking that was best, now I'm not so sure.

Comment: Sink -bath, etc. have traps, purpose of traps is to prevent air from venting through them.  This may be the time to call in the plumber if it is a vent issue.  If this is a two story house, a TEMPORARY quick-fix to try.  On a 2nd floor basin, open up one, and put a shop vac with hose attached to outlet (blower), insert into the drain pipe and see if it will generate enough offsetting pressure.  Use towels to seal it as much as you can.  You will be trying to build up pressure in the drain line.   Even if this works, it is NOT solving the root cause of the original blockage.

Comment: I would look for vents in the in areas above the "inaccessible" area of the drain  pipe.  If a DIY installation, maybe no vents were installed.

Comment: The best way is still to find the air vent and make sure it is not blocked

Comment: Do you know if other drain pipes are connected to the inaccessible section?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this, I'll get investigating some more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106580/discussion-between-programmer66-and-goose).

Comment: SE stated I was discussing too much about the issue, moved me to chat.  Seem strange that SE doesn't like everyone to see all the details of the information that is provided or discussed.   ????

Comment: Yes, SE can be a bit aggressive about rules, but it's pretty good all the same. I've added detail to my question about the vents confirming I can't see any at all, but the stretch of pipes is far from air tight as the central heating system feeds into it with a non-airtight join. I think the vacuum must be being caused close to the sink. I'll look into the pressure tool you suggest. Thanks again for you input, I will come back to this thread once I have a meaningful update.

Comment: Your advice to snake the fully 6m appears to have worked (fingers crossed). Our 6m snake arrived yesterday and we've just sorted it. I'll update my question to give details on what worked incase it helps others.

Comment: When inserting the snake, use back & forth motion with rotation.  Good Luck!!!!